# public string wont return all information

Tags: c#, string, static, public

Trying to figure this out.. have searched for a while but not getting anywhere.

I have the following code in form1 and that is working perfectly.

```
    Connection.tanv = txtUser.Text;
    Connection.tpass = txtPasswd.Text;
    try {
        connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=Diary;username=" + Connection.tanv + ";password=" + Connection.tpass + "");
```

In a class called Connection, I have the following code

```
public class Connection
{
    public static string tanv { get; set; }
    public static string tpass { get; set; }
    public static string strcon = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=Diary;username=" + tanv + ";password=" + tpass + "";
}
```

When I do for example

```
Messagebox.Show(Connection.tanv);
```

I get the correct information

but when I try to do

```
Messagebox.Show(Connection.strcon);
```

I only get the text not the information from the other strings... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set the other two strings before calling the strcon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> public static string strcon = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=Diary;username=" + tanv + ";password=" + tpass + "";
> ```

This is a static field. It is initialised once. When it is initialised, `tanv` and `tpass` are still `null`, so this doesn't do something useful.

You want the string concatenation to happen each time `strcon` is requested. For that, make it a property:

```
public static string strcon => "datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=Diary;username=" + tanv + ";password=" + tpass + "";
//                         ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks solved it for me and made it a bit clearer in the head aswell

Answer (score 2):

Computer programs execute in order.  The order of your execution is (roughly):

1. Allocate space for the `Connection` class.
2. Perform static initialization for the `Connection` class:

   a. `tanv = null`

   b. `tpass = null`

   c. `strcon = string.Concat("datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=Diary;username=", tanv, ";password=", tpass)`
3. Run your other code

   a. set `tanv`

   b. set `tpass`

   c. read `strcon`.

As you can see, the values of `tanv` and `tpass` are set in step 3, too late to be found by the `string.Concat` operation in step 2.

One fix would be to not save the result of `string.Concat` in a static variable, but repeat it each time you read `strcon`.  This is accomplished by creating a field.  hvd shows the shiny new method available in C# 7; for previous versions you'd need to write

```
public static string strcon
{ get { return "datasource=localhost;port=3306;database=Diary;username=" + tanv + ";password=" + tpass + ""; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcon` property is initialised when `tanv` and `tpass` properties are not filled yet. Implement `strcon` property with getter and then it will reflect changes in `tanv` and `tpass`